# Como escrevo em documentos com Python no For

Tags: python

`arquivo = open('escala.txt', 'w')
for i in range(0, 101): 
    var = (i * 2000)/100
    arquivo.white('Temperature is:',i ,'°C  converted is:', var)
arquivo2.close()`

isso não é possivel eu gostaria de saber como se faz isso normalmente

Obs: desculpa sou novo aqui então n sei muito de como pesquisar e perguntar coretamente

Comment: O . white ali, tá certo? não era pra ser .write? e no final, arquivo2.close() deveria ser arquivo.close()

Comment: verdade me desculpa, é possível editar a publicação?

Comment: .write recebe uma string, então vc vai ter que formatar, set iver usando python 3.6 ou maior use fstring, f'Temperatura is:{i} °C converted is: {var}\n'

Comment: obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas melhorando a resposta já dada, algumas dicas.

Você pode utilizar o `with` ao definir o *file handler* em um escopo próprio e assim não precisar fechá-lo do `arquivo.close()` no final.

```py
with open('escala.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    for i in range(0, 101): 
        var = (i * 2000) / 100
        arquivo.write('Temperature is {}oC converted is {}\n'.format(i, var))
```

Uma outra dica é usar o `format()` para montar sua *string* pois além de mais inteligente que o `str()`, permite um melhor controle da apresentação (número de casas decimais, zero à esquerda etc).

Por último uma dica matemática, multiplicar um número por 2000 e depois dividir por 100 é a mesma coisa que só multiplicar por 20, uma operação a menos no final.

Comment: Nossa ajudou muito, obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas coisas erradas no seu script, mas creio que o que você quer fazer é isso aqui:

```
arquivo = open('escala.txt', 'w')
for i in range(0, 101): 
    var = (i * 2000)/100
    escreva = 'Temperature is: '+str(i)+'°C  converted is: '+str(var)+'\n'
    arquivo.write(escreva)
arquivo.close()
```

Comment: obrigado por sua atenção